# PHP Joins – When submitting form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, join

So I am fairly new at PHP. I am writing an app to manage customers with jobs. Basically I want the user to choose a customer and then create a job. Once the job is created. The customer becomes linked with the job. Therefore when the user selects a job he see the customer associated. So how do I link them? What term should I google to do this?

Also I am getting the client name thru a PHP query from DB.
I am doing this through a from, his the code of the form.

```
<form action="nc_job.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate" id="job">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="w4-jt" class="tab-pane active">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Services</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">

        <?php
          mysql_connect("localhost", "mydb", "mypass") or
            die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
          mysql_select_db("itrack_psa");

          $sql = "SELECT v1 FROM services";
          $result = mysql_query($sql);

          echo "<select name='v1' data-plugin-selectTwo class='form-control populate' >";

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value="Not Assigned">Not Assigned</option>';
            echo "<option value='" . $row['v1'] . "'>" . $row['v1'] . "</option>";
          }

          echo "</select>";
        ?>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Additional Details</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div name="v2" class="summernote"  data-plugin-summernote 
               data-plugin-options='{ "height": 180, "codemirror": { "theme": "ambiance" } }'>
            Type Here
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-------------------------------->
    <div id="w4-sc" class="tab-pane">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="inputDefault">Job Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="v3">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Client</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">

        <?php
          mysql_connect("localhost", "mydb", "mypass") or
            die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
          mysql_select_db("itrack_psa");

          $sql = "SELECT `v2`, `v3` FROM client";
          $result = mysql_query($sql);

          echo "<select name='v4' data-plugin-selectTwo class='form-control populate' >";

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value="Not Assigned">Not Assigned</option>';
            echo "<option value='" . $row['v2'] . $row['v3'] ."'>" . $row['v2'] . $row['v3'] . "</option>";
          }

          echo "</select>";
        ?>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Day</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </span>
            <input name="v5" type="text" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Start Time</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
            </span>
            <input name="v6" type="text" data-plugin-timepicker class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">End Time</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
            </span>
            <input name="v7" type="text" data-plugin-timepicker class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-------------------------------->
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <ul class="pager">
        <li class="previous disabled">
          <a><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li type="submit" class="finish hidden pull-right">
          <a  href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('job').submit();">Create</a>
        </li>
        <li class="next">
          <a>Next <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: this "data-plugin-selectTwo" tag. Can you please give me a link on documentation to read more about it?

Answer (score 0):

You need following things to achieve this

1. Create  tables - User,Jobs,Customers

   User      - UID,Name,Email...
   Customer  - Customer_ID,Name
   Job       - JobId,JobDetails,UID,Customer_ID
2. So when user will create/post job insert data into job table with selected customer id, and user id[ assuming logged in user]
3. Fetch Result - [Select job] So when User select Job ,create sql join on jobs and customer table with selected job id

**Example**

Note : Make sure table fields

```
Select j.*,C.cust_name from jobs as j Left join customer as C On j.Customer_ID= C.Customer_ID where j.jobid=selectedjobid
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am trying it now.